# A .tiff library for Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, canvas, base64

Is there a library like [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js) (please look at createBMP function) for making .tiff in JavaScript (browser or nodejs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native browser-support for tiff files is still pretty bad. Wikipedia has a nice overview regarding browser [Image format support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

That being said; since a .tiff image is still essentially a raster-image, one could indeed convert it (the tricky part is stuff like supporting different compression-algorithms like PACKBITS, DEFLATE, LZW, etc) to another (browser-supported) raster-format (so one could feed it as a `data:img`-source).

There is a library called **[Tiffus](https://github.com/sugark/Tiffus)**: a client side pure Javascript imaging library to load, save and manipulate binary images.

The original project aim was was to create a plain Javascript chrome extension which can convert single/multi page TIFF image/s to BMP/GIF image (this is where the name came from).

However now it supports:

- Windows BMP (no compression, RLE)
- OS/2 BMP
- ICO
- GIF
- JPEG
- PNG
- TIFF

and currently supports the folloing image functions:

- load
- save
- resize
- flip
- invert color

Basically it works like this:

1. Source image downloaded as Binary Data using XMLHttpRequest with
   MimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'); (future: HTML5
   Canvas ImageData)
2. Imageprocessing using Tiffus
3. Destination image shown as Data URI scheme (future: HTML5 Canvas ImageData)

Note that according to the above; the author expects to use HTML5 Canvas `ImageData` in the future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a repository for this which doesn't require me to install the bloated java stack?