# How to generate pdf and tiff image on the client using client technologies

Tags: jquery, wcf

Currently I am generating pdf and tiff image using asp.net generic handler. I would like to generate pdf and tiff image on client using byte array received from server.

We started migrating our asp.net server based web application to client based web application. We made use of WCF to get data from server and using client technologies we represent data on the browser.

I tried to use jspdf to generate pdf on client, but I don't find proper API's to pass byte array and generate pdf. Additionally i should be able to generate tiff images too.

I cant use itextsharp too as I don't store files physically. PDF and tiff content will be stored in DB as byte array. This byte array will be fetched and should be shown as PDF and tiff on the client. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Tiffs check [tiffus](https://code.google.com/p/tiffus/) 
More about client side tiffs [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138297/a-tiff-library-for-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to generate the PDF and TIFF on the client side in the first place? To simply avoid server side processing and some CPU? I don't think this in the long run is a scale-able solution. What if a new requirement for generating some other formats come up in the future? What if you want to support a new platform which the existing hypothetical component does not support? 
The setup we have in our organisation is like the following:
We have a reporting server machine which is responsible for managing the queues of requested reports and generating them. then we send the user the link to download these reports. We periodically remove files older than N days.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with your comments. Similar to this server side programming dont we have any client components which generate files of all formats by specifying the content type? Due to security issues I cant write file to physical location. I have to generate pdf of tiff on the fly.

Comment: If security is an issue the only reliable solution which comes to my mind is having a client side application [Microsoft .Net Forms for instance] which queries your WCF service directly after authentication and generates the report based on the required format. Countless components for generating all sorts of format are available.